# find feature for the mongodb module is not working in my Nextjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js

I have a nextjs application I have been developing and need to find all the documents in one of my collections I am using the mongodb node module. when i use .find() to pull the documents I just get an empty JSON object. I use .findOne, .updateOne with out any issues for my login and password reset pages. here is my code from the api.

```js
     try{
      const client = await connectDatabase();
      const events = client.db().collection('members');
      const documents = events.find()
      res.status(200).json( documents);}catch(error){
      res.status(500).json({message: error.message});}
```

I have looked all over the mongodb documentation and have not found a solution to this issue.
this is what I get back when I run the code {"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0}

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `.find()` returns a cursor so you can iterate it, the best you can do here is transform it into an array like below:

```
const documents = await events.find().toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB query is asynchronous, so you need to wait for the response. Change your code like this:

```js
const documents = await events.find();
```

Comment: Thank you for seeing that but it did not change the results from the query using .find() I have even tried using .find({}) and still have not returned any data.